# How to check which git tag release a particular file was introduced in?

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a bunch of files that I want to know which release they were introduced in. In bulk. The releases are tagged in git.

What's the easiest way to quickly check large (~80) number of files' presence in multiple (~10) tags ?

I can write some custom code to check out each tag to a directory, look for the files present on the file system, etc.

Is there a faster, more 'git' way to do that?

Thinking of git as a graph, I guess the pure implementation is to trace the history to the origin commit, then forward to the tags containing that commit. But, unless there is a tool already to do so, this is probably a more complicated approach than checking out the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git tag --contains <commit>` prints all the tags that are "at or downstream of" the given commit.  You then need only pick the "first" such tag (if your tags are numbered simply, e.g., `v1.7` `v1.8` `v2.0` that's probably trivial, if they're complicated like `v1.7a` `v1.7alpha` `v1.7-0` `v1.7.0` `v1.7`<sup>1</sup> then you'll need some other way to pick the right one, such as minimizing the graph "distance" from all the candidate tags).

`git log --pretty=format:%H --diff-filter=A -1 -- path` prints the first commit-ID in which the given *`path`* is `A`dded (you might want `--no-renames`, or maybe a specific `-M` level and/or `-C` options, to tweak whether git might consider a file renamed or copied, in terms of finding the commit).

Combining these two will get you there pretty quickly, I think.

---

<sup>1</sup>I just made these up and I *still* have no idea whether `v1.7` comes before or after `v1.7.0` here, nor what relation `v1.7-0` and `v1.7a` have to those two.  I've seen crazy stuff like this "for real" before—usually after Marketing gets their hands on things—although I made this up just for illustration.

Comment: This seems to work most of the time. I have an extra wrinkle that the backing repo is SVN managed and they used an *svn copy* for a file in the release branch copied to trunk. Which, for git, created a completely separate history it seems. So, the file never showed up in the *tag* from *trunk*'s point of view. But that's probably a too-strange a use-case to worry about.

Comment: That (separate history) makes sense and you'd have to do something more complex for such a case.  (Also, I should note that `-M` and `-C` require modifying the `--diff-filter` and not limiting the log to one commit and particular paths, so it also gets more complex.)